# QPDF giving file not found error in python

Tags: python, qpdf

[image]I am using qpdf to decrpyt pdf files (encrytpted but without password) as pypdf2 decryption doesn't work.
It is working on command line but with python giving `FileNotFoundError`

```
qpdf --decrypt --replace-input test.pdf # it's working; replacing test.pdf with the absolute path
```

But with python it doesn't

```
inp_file = open(self.path, "rb")
inp_pdf = PdfFileReader(inp_file)
if inp_pdf.isEncrypted:
    try:
        inp_pdf.decrypt('')
    except:
        subprocess.run(["qpdf", "--decrypt", "--replace-input", self.path)])
```

Comment: Try to give qpdf the full-path.

Comment: giving full-path, but still the error

Comment: With a debugger, you should investigate if "FileNotFoundError" is related to qpdf or to self.path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [pikepdf](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It is built on top of QPDF; brief description in quotes below. It's very simple to create new pdfs based on exisiting pdfs. Also, it handles decryption on the fly.

> Pikepdf provides a Pythonic wrapper around the C++ PDF content transformation library, QPDF.

It doesn't implement text extraction from pdfs; I used tika for text extraction.